# rollup: How do I prepend a line to the beginning of my file?

Tags: javascript, rollup

I am using rollup to generate a single JavaScript file. I want to put a line at the beginning of this JavaScript file that looks like this:

```
This is a line of my choosing
```

I'd been googling for a while and can't figure out how to do this. I found a banner plug-in, but the problem is it puts a comment at the beginning of the line you prepend, and I don't want that. I found and insert plug-in, but that inserted the line on every file, and it did it inside the iife.  I want this line only once at the beginning of the file and outside the IIFE.

**How do you prepend a line to the beginning of your rollup output file?**

Comment: Can't you just create a dummy header file, then combine it at the end with your shell or even JavaScript readfile/writefile?

Comment: @KaseyChang That is how I solved it, what can it be done in rollup?

Comment: Good question. I'd try a) "reading a file from stdin" and b) would "banner" text work for you? Supposedly it's an option to label the bundle before the actual bundle content.

Answer (score 6):

desen't the 'output.banner' option itself work?

```
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  ...,
  output: {
    ...,
    banner: 'This is a line of my choosing',
  }
};
```